# Servlet Filter and Spring REST controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlet-filters, spring-restcontroller

I have a simple Servlet filter that looks for a header in the request and if the header is missing, then it sets a value to it before it sends the actual request to the Spring Rest controller class.

Example: the client code sets foo=bar, then the filter doesn't do anything. If the client does not set it, then the filter sets something.

When I switch my implementation to a plain-old Java servlet, then the servlet sees the header value set by the filter.

What the Rest controller gets is the headers set by the actual client.

Example: client sets the header foo=bar, then the controller gets the value bar for “foo”.

Assuming that the value for foo is not set by the client and the filter sets it, then the controller doesn’t see it and it gets the value as null.

**Spring Rest Code:**

```
@ResponseBody 
  public ResponseEntity<Foo> process(@PathVariable(value="myValue") String myValue, @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers) {   
    logger.info("Foo header value is " + header.get("foo"));
    //Gets printed as null when the filter sets the value
    //Prints the actual value when the client code sets it.


  }
```

**Servlet Code:**

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        logger.info("Foo header is " + req.getHeader("foo"));
        //Prints the value all the time
        //When Client sets it, then it prints the value set by Client
        //When Client does not set it, then it prints the value set by Filter
      }
```

Interestingly when I have something like this in my Rest Controller, then I get the header value where I am auto-wiring the HttpServletRequest object.

Clearly I see that Spring's HttpHeaders ignores the header value set by the filter.

```
 @Autowired
  HttpServletRequest req;

  @ResponseBody 
  public ResponseEntity<Foo> process(@PathVariable(value="myValue") String myValue) {   
    logger.info("Foo value is " + req.getHeader("foo"));
    //Now I get it all the time

  }
```

Wondering what the issue is.

My environment is Spring 4, Java 8 and Tomcat 8.

Comment: have you tried this (   @RequestHeader(value="foo") String foo ) ?
Also, are you using org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders ?

Comment: Then it expects the client to set "foo". If not the client sets it, then the rest controller crashes throwing a 500.

Comment: Oh, ok, I see. Is using required=false and defaultValue in the RequestHeader a solution ? Or is it more of a calculated value ?

Comment: You are using a HttpServletRequestWrapper in your filter to add your header, right ?

Comment: Yes, I use HttpServletRequestWrapper :)

Comment: Five years later... I am incurring similar abnormal behavior.  @RequestParam("foo") is independent of filter changes, yet @RequestHeader Map<String, String> requestHeaders produces a map that contains a filter adjusted "foo" value.